# is it possible to get insert id without commit in postgresql

Tags: python

Now I want to insert a article record into two PostgreSQL(version 13) table, one table contain the article base info, and the other table contains the article content(maybe move to another db in the future). Here is the problem that sometimes one save sql failed make the data lose.

now I want the two action both success or both failed, but the content table must get the base table's id to insert. is it possible to get the base table insert id before commit? so that I could commit at one places. This is my python 3 code:

```
   def save_single(self, guid, pub_time, title, author, content, feed_url):
        if content is not None and len(content) > 0:
            article = ArticleService()
            article = article.save(title, guid, author, pub_time)
            content = ArticleContentService()
            if article.id is not None:
                content.save(article.id, content)
        else:
            logger.error("article content is null,title:" + title)
```

what should I do to make data keep consistant? the database orm library is `sqlalchemy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Most likely your id is autoincrement and is generated when you commit to the database.

As for doing both things at once, yes. If you have a parent:child relationship set up, you can append the child to the parent and just commit the parent.

Comment: do you have any example code? I tried but failed. this is the project address and code:https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/pydolphin.git  show this error:`Message: 'subscribe data error'
Arguments: (InvalidRequestError("When initializing mapper mapped class ArticleService->article, expression 'ArticleContentService' failed to locate a name ('ArticleContentService'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'dolphin.common.db.ArticleService.ArticleService'> class after both dependent classes have been defined."),)` @Clinton Bradfield

Comment: Please see: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many . At the very bottom, above the "dragons-be-here" there's an example of properly appending children to parents.